# How do I create a fixed left container which runs down the page vertically to display a list of skills?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Forgive me, I am brand new to web dev. As my first project, I am building a resume page. I want a fixed left div where I can list my skills, with a larger div to the right hand side, to fill the remaining body content for employment history etc...?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Resume</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg bg-dark fs-5"
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img src="homepage-pic.png" alt="" width="75" height="75">
   </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="d-flex" role="search">
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

<!-- Skills -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[position: fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) is what you're looking for. (or sticky, depends on your needs)

Sample use:

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fixed {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="fixed"></div>
```

Also tip for newbie - if you're starting your webdev journey, start without css framework. Will be easier to understand some basic concepts faster.

Comment: Hi @TheTanadu, thank you for your helpful tips! this hasn't had my desired effect, what has happened is I now have two large, split green containers on top of each other, filling up the entire page. What I want is my skills section to the left (vertical) and the main content to the right of this for employment history (horizontal)

Comment: I gave you an answer to question "how", of what property you need to achieve your goal and simple example how it works. A ready-made solution is not studying.

Comment: As you mentioned you are learning, you're in early stages. If you want to use bootstrap then maybe in their docs you can search for "positioning" (there's your answer of their made-up class)?